# getaddrinfo Name or service not known Socket Error s3 fog carrierwave Figaro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having the problem when i am using amazon s3 services

the **error** is

```
Excon::Errors::SocketError in PhotosController#create 
getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)}
```

This error occur when i try to save the image.

**config/initializers/carrierwave.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
config.fog_credentials = {
:provider               => 'AWS',                        
:aws_access_key_id      => 'XXXXX',                        
:aws_secret_access_key  => 'YYYYY',                        
:region                 => 'us-east-1',                  
:host                   => 's3.example.com',             
:endpoint               => 'https://s3.example.com:8080'
```

}

```
config.fog_directory  = 'My_bucket_name'                       
config.fog_public     = false                            
config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>"max-age=#{365.day.to_i}"}
```

end

i am using figaro.gem

**config/application.yml**

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE: aaaaaa 
AWS_ACCES_KEY_ID: XXXXXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: YYYYYY
AWS_BUCKET: "My_bucket_name"
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem "figaro"
```

**app/uploaders/picture_uploader.rb**

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

storage :fog


def store_dir
'uploads/data'
end


end
```

i followed this site [enter link description here](http://blog.thefirehoseproject.com/posts/switching-carrierwave-to-use-s3-with-heroku-and-localhost/) and didn't made any changes other configurations.

i have deployed my application to heroku. i want to upload images/videos to that application.
can anyone help or suggest me to how to upload images/videos to heroku with using carrierwave.

Thanks advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because there is no such host: `s3.example.com`.

Remove `host` and `endpoint` keys from `config.fog_credentials` hash.